# how to pull and trigger pop up box with related data on extjs grid?

Tags: php, extjs

I have a paginated grid with data in it, so here's my code

```
  var pagesize = 5;

  Ext.onReady(function(){
    var invoice = new Ext.data.Store({
         proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
             url: 'classes/invoices.php',
        //method: 'POST'
          }),
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
         root: 'rows',
         totalProperty: 'results',
        fields: ['InvoiceID','InvoiceNumber','UserID','CompanyID','Date','InvoiceTo',
        'AddressLine1','Addressline2','AddressLine3','AddressLine4','AddressLine5',
        'AddressLine6','Country','ZipCode','Description'],
    }),

  remoteSort: false
  });
  var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    frame: true,
    title: 'Invoices',
    height: 200,
    width: 1135,
    store: invoice,
    colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    defaultSortable: false,
        columns: [
        {header: "Invoice ID", dataIndex: 'InvoiceID' },
        {header: "Invoice Number", dataIndex:'InvoiceNumber'},
        //{header: "User ID", dataIndex: 'UserID'},
        //{header: "Company ID", dataIndex: 'CompanyID'},
        {header: "Date", dataIndex: 'Date'},
        {header: "Invoice To", dataIndex: 'InvoiceTo'},
        {header: "AddressLine1", dataIndex: 'AddressLine1'},
        {header: "AddressLine2", dataIndex: 'AddressLine2'},
        {header: "AddressLine3", dataIndex: 'AddressLine3'},
        {header: "AddressLine4", dataIndex: 'AddressLine4'},
        {header: "AddressLine5", dataIndex: 'AddressLine5'},
        {header: "AddressLine6", dataIndex: 'AddressLine6'},
        {header: "Country", dataIndex: 'Country'}
            ]
    }),
    bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
       store: invoice,
       displayInfo: true,
       pageSize: pagesize,
       prependButtons: true,
       items:[
         'test'
       ]
    }),
    sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
      singleSelect: true,
      listeners: {
        rowselect: function(sm, index, record){
         Ext.Msg.alert('You Selected',record.get('InvoiceNumber'));
        }
      }
    })
  });
  invoice.load({
        params: {
          start: 0,
          limit: pagesize,
        }
    });
  });
```

What I want to happen now is, if I click one of the rows in the Grid, a grid will pop out that has the data related to the clicked row, so how to do that , what code to insert? , any how's the coding in PHP?, any samples or direct code help is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check Sencha documentation for the itemclick event for the grid - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-itemclick